SSH passwordless failing
I am trying to set access through SSH between nodes in a data center with keys.
All nodes share a file space so I am setting all in the ~/.ssh/ folder.
I already did:

Generated a SSH key (and stored it in the ~/.ssh/id_rsa file). I set a passphrase for this
Started the SSH agent, and added the private key to the agent
Confirmed that the key is loaded into the agent
Append the public key to the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file
Set permission 700 for the ~/.ssh folder and 600 for the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file

So now I am trying to confirm the setup and I do:
$ssh -v me@node11

And it asks me to enter my password (which is what I am trying to prevent).
Running it verbose it says:
$ssh -v me@node11
...
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /mnt/pacific/thecompany/me/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /mnt/pacific/thecompany/me/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /mnt/pacific/thecompany/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /mnt/pacific/thecompany/me/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
me@compute11's password:

What is it that I am overlooking to allow non interactive SSH access through nodes?
EDIT: This question has been closed on the basis that it already has an answer. It does not. The linked question has similarities but their log says clearly debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm which is key for the accepted answer.
This does not happen in this question.
Any help for this question is appreciated

"All nodes share a file space" -- Does this mean you expect the changes you did to the local ~/.ssh/authorized_keys to apply to other nodes? Log in with your password and confirm it's really the case.

I have used srun to launch an interactive bash session on the nodes I am interested. From there I see the same file space
